# Mail not received - SingleEmailMessage

Tags: email

I'm trying to send mails to the owners of the Campaigns on certain conditions using SingleEmailMessage. While i could see no error in debug the mails seems not being recieved @ my inbox. Below the code snippet....any inputs to correct this or troubleshoot please?

```
public static void sendMail(List<Campaign> Campaigns){
    for(Campaign camp:campaigns){
        //New instance of a single email message
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        // Recipient
        mail.setTargetObjectId(camp.CreatedById);
        // Set the mail template
        mail.setTemplateId('00X26000000DbPe');
        mail.setBccSender(false);
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        //mail.setWhatid(camp.Id);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Nb: I'm trying to trigger the mail by testing it using the annotation @isTest for the class...

Comment: if you are using @isTest then nothing will be sent. No actual emails are sent during test methods. Use Dev console to execute the class and send the email

Comment: Thought experiment -- imagine if testmethods would actually send email. Result of thought experiment: "Much, much, much unwanted spam and worse, false positive emails sent to real people indicating orders fulfilled, accounts cancelled, etc  - and repeated on every testmethod execution"

Comment: n.b. triggers that send email messages are likely to run into governor limits as you are limited on # outbound apex emails PER DAY across whole org. Much better to set boolean in sobject and let workflow send email alert

Comment: @crop1645 - **Thought Experiment** - consider that phrase stolen.....So many well placed opportunities to use it.....Oh and what is "n.b" ?

Comment: Did you see any issue in the email logs? You can check here on how to request for email logs.https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs_edit.htm

Comment: @Eric - `n.b.` = `nota bene` == "by the way".  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103318/nota-bene-in-technical-writing. Although it appears I have been not capitalizing it per rules: `N.B.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. @IsTest methods will never send emails. Thought experiment -- imagine if testmethods would actually send email. Result of thought experiment: "Much, much, much unwanted spam and worse, false positive emails sent to real people indicating orders fulfilled, accounts cancelled, etc - and repeated on every testmethod execution"
2. You are hard-coding the email templateId -- this is not best practice as the template Id in sandbox will not be the same when you deploy to PROD.  Better to query for the template's Id from Sobject `EmailTemplate`
3. Using apex outbound email may hit a governor limit as there is an org wide DAILY limit across all transactions - check [Limits guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) for latest maximimum;  Winter 16 = 1000. Better solutions involve setting a boolean field on the target object and then having a workflow/process builder use email alerts and field update (to reset the boolean).  Or, [here are some other alternatives](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/how-can-you-avoid-hitting-24-hour-limits-on-emails-and-future-calls). If you insist on using outbound apex email, you should use the `reserveSingleEmailCapacity()` method to avoid getting a limits error and also providing for some graceful alternative for the transaction.

Comment: they killed the Workaround using workflow email alerts. They are now limited to 1,000 per 24 hours per license  (has this limit always been there? IIRC the limits doc used to say unlimited for WF)

Comment: @Eric -- really? I interpreted this statement ` Single emails sent using the Salesforce application don't count toward this limit` as meaning that workflow-based email alerts are not bound by the 1000 limit.  Also - this help article states 1000 email alerts per user license: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_email_limits.htm - so 100 user licenses = 100,000 email alerts per day

Comment: @Eric -- BTW, I think you should really get credit for the answer here as your first comment to the OP was the right answer - post an answer and hopefully OP will mark it as the 'answer'

Comment: Yea, but for those small orgs with only says 1 admin that do email functionality for their users (say sending renewal emails for large companies) it presents a problem - and no worries on the credits, main goal is that the OP learns something from it and other can as well. Your write up is much more details. Plus you should get mucho point for "Thought Experiment" lol - Besides, it does not look like the OP is going to mark the answer as accepted just like so many other one time posters

Comment: @Eric -- hadn't thought about your use case - few users, many emails.  It is hard sometimes to work around SFDC's innate goal of getting one's org to buy more user licenses

Comment: yea, I have a client that processes AV renewals for major retailers. They wanted to send receipts and I said to use workflow as there is no limit. Low and Behold they imposed this limit and I had to eat my words (I know it used to be unlimited). The org only has two users so they were pushed toward ExactTarget, then the implementation partner messed everything up and could not resolve a future calling future in a ET trigger from ExactTarget (they wanted my to fix it but managed package and all)..So they dumped ET and are now stuck using external service....CSV heaven UGH