# Using Apex, how do I monitor the daily @future limits?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, future

[This](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385816&type=1) support article indicates that I have a limit of 250k @future methods per day. However, I can't find the corresponding Limit class function to monitor this limit. I've tried:

```
System.debug(Limits.getFutureCalls());
System.debug(Limits.getLimitFutureCalls());
```

Both of these seem to deal with a single Execution context.

I've also reviewed the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_System_limits_getAsyncCalls), but can't find one that fits.
This [Exchange answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/how-can-you-avoid-hitting-24-hour-limits-on-emails-and-future-calls) seems to indicate the answer is "you can't" but that seems preposterous that Salesforce sets a limit that you can't monitor, so I hope I'm reading it wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [sfdcfox pointed out](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/413870/102), this is a [shared limit for all async operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#in_topic_non_transactional_gov_limits_section) in the org.

You can monitor this directly in Apex via the OrgLimits class.

```
Map<String,System.OrgLimit> limitsMap = OrgLimits.getMap();

System.OrgLimit apiRequestsLimit = limitsMap.get('DailyAsyncApexExecutions');
System.debug('Limit Name: ' + apiRequestsLimit.getName());
System.debug('Usage Value: ' + apiRequestsLimit.getValue());
System.debug('Maximum Limit: ' + apiRequestsLimit.getLimit());
```

> 07:45:33.31 (31463597)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
> 07:45:33.31 (135567734)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Limit Name: **DailyAsyncApexExecutions**
> 07:45:33.31 (135767388)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|Usage Value: **0**
> 07:45:33.31 (135896547)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|Maximum Limit: **250000**

Comment: I must have missed that when it came out. The last couple of years have been challenging, to say the least.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I just introduced it into my solution and it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Note that future methods don't have their own limit. The limits are shared across schedulable, batchable, queueable, and future methods. There's no way to get this data *directly* in Apex, but the [Limits API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm) has the `DailyAsyncApexExecutions` property which will tell you how many calls you get per day, and how many remain. This requires a callout, though, so you can't find out this information in some contexts. One possible example would be a schedulable class. See the demo below.

[Demo](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/d193db3dd7ff369f0dae9118938737d1).

Comment: Thank you for the extra detail. With this information, it seems the best design would be to monitor this limit externally instead of trying to build a Limit callout into every async process. I think I'll propose building an external schedules job into our SF proxy that periodically checks the limits we care about and sends an email if they pass a certain threshold.

Comment: Looks like I can't upvote you as my account is new. But thanks again for the help!

Comment: @JacksonSardello You could write an hourly scheduled job to call the API and write the data somewhere or notify someone. Lots of options exist, just there's no call you can do directly in Apex. Don't worry about the upvote, I have plenty already. You'll get some reputation for accepting, and I've given you an upvote to get you closer to the right to upvote. Enjoy your stay here, and hopefully we'll see you around.

Comment: The ability to call the REST API for the current org requires a session, right? A non-null return from `UserInfo.getSessionId` depends on the context of invocation. I don't think a scheduled job would have access to this session ID, so you may need to jump hoops with a Connected App...?

Comment: I think you're correct @PhilW. My comment about an "external scheduled job" is in line with your suggestion about setting up a Connect App. We have an external application that could manage such a task. I think I would run into problems with scheduled job directly in Salesforce.

Comment: @PhilW they changed it some time ago. If the context user is active and not Automated Process, you can get the session Id without any hoops. Just call UserInfo.getSessionId as normal.

Comment: @JacksonSardello you can get a valid session Id these days. But you'll have to use queuable or future to complete the callout.

Comment: That's learning #2 for today... it's been a good one for learning!

Comment: No need for a callout to get this, you can use the OrgLimits class directly - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/413931/102